# Is there any way to generate pom.xml by uploading script?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I need to create a pom.xml  to use in gitlab ci/cd
Anybody know any easy way to generate a pom.xml ?
My project is : terraform code will generate 6 instance on was and then cp-ansible script will install Kafka on them

Comment: An empty POM? Or a POM for a given list of dependencies? Or what?

Comment: @JFabianMeier a POM with given list of dependency ?

Comment: Is this a question? It is easy to generate a `pom.xml`. Copy one from MavenCentral. We need to know what content the POM should have...